# How to do a simple entity copy in Linq-to-SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql, copy, clone

When using a Linq-to-SQL class, how can I make a simple copy of an entity and save it?

My entity has a guid for a unique ID that gets automatically generated in the SQL Server.

I don't require a "deep clone".

I tried to use [some clone methods that are out there](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic/insights/779607-clone-any-object-vb-6-0-a) but I couldn't figure out how to get everything serialized that needed to be serialized (got stuck on the `DataContext` not being serializable).

Can I just get an entity, detach it from the `DataContext`, null out the unique ID and `InsertOnSubmit` in a new `DataContext`?  If so, how would I do this?

VB.net code preferred but not required.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
**UPDATE:**

```
Public Shared Function ReIssue(RequestID As Guid) As Guid

    Dim req As Request
    Dim new_req As Request

    Using dc1 As New MBDataContext()
        req = (From r In dc1.Requests Where r.ID = RequestID).Single()
    End Using

    new_req = req
    new_req.ID = Guid.Empty
    new_req.CreateDate = Nothing

    Using dc2 As New MBDataContext()
        dc2.Requests.InsertOnSubmit(new_req)
        dc2.SubmitChanges()
    End Using

End Function
```

I get an error: *An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext.  This is not supported.*

on this line: dc2.Requests.InsertOnSubmit(new_req)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This method](http://mehmetcatkin.com/post/2010/09/Easy-way-to-copy-an-entitiy-in-linq-to-sql.aspx) seems to have worked perfectly.

Making the final code look like this:

```
Public Shared Function ReIssue(RequestID As Guid) As Guid

    Using dc As New MBDataContext()
        Dim req As Request
        req = (From r In dc.Requests Where r.ID = RequestID).Single()

        Dim new_req As Request = DirectCast(Entity.Copy(req, New Request()), Request)

        dc.Requests.InsertOnSubmit(new_req)
        dc.SubmitChanges()

        req.ActiveRequestParentID = new_req.ID
        dc.SubmitChanges()

        Return new_req.ID
    End Using

End Function

Public NotInheritable Class Entity

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Copy(source As Object, destination As Object) As Object
        Dim sourceProps As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo() = source.[GetType]().GetProperties()
        Dim destinationProps As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo() = destination.[GetType]().GetProperties()
        For Each sourceProp As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In sourceProps
            Dim column As ColumnAttribute = TryCast(Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(sourceProp, GetType(ColumnAttribute)), ColumnAttribute)
            If column IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not column.IsPrimaryKey Then
                For Each destinationProp As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In destinationProps
                    If sourceProp.Name = destinationProp.Name AndAlso destinationProp.CanWrite Then
                        destinationProp.SetValue(destination, sourceProp.GetValue(source, Nothing), Nothing)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
        Return destination
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Nulling out the unique id and then calling `InsertOnSubmit` is the right way to go.  Some things you have to consider though:

- What is the type of the id?  Is it an `int`?  A `Guid`?  Is it nullable?  If it is nullable, make sure to set it to null, if it is an `int`, then to 0, or a `Guid`, then to `Guid.Empty`.
- Does the type have a timestamp of some kind?  If so, then you have to reset/set it to null as well, depending on the type.

Once you've done that, you can call `InsertOnSubmit` and then `SubmitChanges` and the change should take place.

Note, if you are doing this for a large number of records, you are better off writing a stored procedure which will perform the insert into the table using a select from the other table.  It will be *much* faster that way (you won't be loading the data from the database into memory then pushing it back, inserting the records one at a time).

Comment: Ahh, Guid.Empty might be the critical piece that I was missing.  I'll try that real quick.  Do, I need to detach first, or can I just do it all in the same `DataContext`?  (also, thanks for cleaning up my post - I'll keep that post-style in mind)

Comment: @EdenMachine: You will have to create a new `DataContext`, as there is no way to detach the entity from the original.  The original will still be tracking the instance if you try to use the same one, and it should result in an error.

Comment: @casperOne - I updated the code as you suggested and posted the new error that I get now.

Comment: Also, answer your questions.  The unique ID is a non-nullable uniqueidentifier (guid) that is auto-created inside SQL Server.  The CreateDate is a datetime that is also autocreated in SQL Server using GetDate().  I set in the DBML that these properties are Auto Generated as well.  I only need to copy one entity - not multiple ones.

Comment: @EdenMachine: You didn't do as I suggested; there is no construction of a new `DataContext`.  You should only have to set the unique id, but it wouldn't hurt to set `CreateDate` to null/Empty/Zero as well.

Comment: @casperOne - I updated the code portion again to better reflect what I think you are suggesting.  Am I way off base because I still get the same error?